# Default maximum string length in REST API?

Tags: spring-boot, validation, openapi

I have a REST API defined in an OpenAPI 3.0.1 spec, from which Java classes are generated using the [Openapi Spring Code Generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/spring/).

To prevent abuse, the length of all string fields should be limited to 5000 characters unless otherwise specified.
This works fine for the fields that have a maxLength set in the API spec, but most don't have anything set.

Is there a good solution to define a default either in the spec or in Spring Boot (remember that model classes are auto-generated from the spec on every build)?

I couldn't find anything except for `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size`, but since there are also endpoints for uploading files, this is not a viable option.

Anything that makes this task easier than manually adding `maxLength: 5000` to a few thousand fields would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Problem

You have identified a need to have a default maxLength set on all String items in your API.

## Solution

This can easily be done using the provided mustache templates.  Here's how.

#### Testing schema

I used the following schema for testing.

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info:
  title: My-API
  version: 0.0.1
servers:
  - url: 'https://{api}.{server}/{basePath}'
    variables:
      api:
        default: "mywebsite"
        description: "This is my website api"
      server:
        default: "production"
      basePath:
        default: "v2"
paths:
  /simpleValidationTest:
    get:
      operationId: setValue
      responses:
        "200":
          description: OK
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/testingStringValidation'
      summary: get modules
      tags:
        - Modules
components:
  schemas:
    testingStringValidation:
      type: object
      properties:
        validatedString:
          type: string
          maxLength: 25
        unvalidatedString:
          type: string
        unvalidatedInteger:
          type: integer
        validatedInteger:
          type: integer
          minimum: 2
```

This schema has validation and no validation on both a string and an integer.  This will ensure that our generated model applies the expected default validation

#### Mustache Template

The Spring generator has a template called `beanValidationCore.mustache`.  This template handles all of your bean validation.  This template is called from `pojo.mustache` in this segment:

```
{{#beanValidation}}
{{>beanValidation}}
{{/useBeanValidation}}
```

This tells the templating engine that, if it is supposed to use beanValidation (`{{#beanValidation}}`), than at this point, it will call the `beanValidation` template (`{{>beanValidation}}`).  **Note:** The `>` means use another template.

In my brief testing, this always evaluated to true.  I checked the documentation, and [it claims](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/docs/generators/spring.md) that `useBeanValidation` defaults to false.  However, looking at the code, this is [clearly not true](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/java/org/openapitools/codegen/languages/SpringCodegen.java#L152).  So, all we need to do is update `beanValidationCore.mustache` to provide a default.  This is easily done by inserting the following snippet on lines 8 and 9 of the template

```
minLength not set, maxLength not set
}}{{^minLength}}{{^maxLength}}{{#isString}}@Size(max = 5000) {{/isString}}{{/maxLength}}{{/minLength}}{{!
```

This will now check if the item to be validated is a String.  If it is, and maxLength is not set, then it will apply the annotation `@Size(max = 5000)` to the field.

#### Generated Code

Using my api above and the new template, I got the following results in my pojo.

```java
public class TestingStringValidation implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @JsonProperty("validatedString")
  private String validatedString;

  @JsonProperty("unvalidatedString")
  private String unvalidatedString;

  @JsonProperty("unvalidatedInteger")
  private Integer unvalidatedInteger;

  @JsonProperty("validatedInteger")
  private Integer validatedInteger;

  public TestingStringValidation validatedString(String validatedString) {
    this.validatedString = validatedString;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get validatedString
   * @return validatedString
  */
  @Size(max = 25) 
  @Schema(name = "validatedString", required = false)
  public String getValidatedString() {
    return validatedString;
  }

  public void setValidatedString(String validatedString) {
    this.validatedString = validatedString;
  }

  public TestingStringValidation unvalidatedString(String unvalidatedString) {
    this.unvalidatedString = unvalidatedString;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get unvalidatedString
   * @return unvalidatedString
  */
  @Size(max = 5000) 
  @Schema(name = "unvalidatedString", required = false)
  public String getUnvalidatedString() {
    return unvalidatedString;
  }

  public void setUnvalidatedString(String unvalidatedString) {
    this.unvalidatedString = unvalidatedString;
  }

  public TestingStringValidation unvalidatedInteger(Integer unvalidatedInteger) {
    this.unvalidatedInteger = unvalidatedInteger;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get unvalidatedInteger
   * @return unvalidatedInteger
  */
  
  @Schema(name = "unvalidatedInteger", required = false)
  public Integer getUnvalidatedInteger() {
    return unvalidatedInteger;
  }

  public void setUnvalidatedInteger(Integer unvalidatedInteger) {
    this.unvalidatedInteger = unvalidatedInteger;
  }

  public TestingStringValidation validatedInteger(Integer validatedInteger) {
    this.validatedInteger = validatedInteger;
    return this;
  }

  /**
   * Get validatedInteger
   * minimum: 2
   * @return validatedInteger
  */
  @Min(2) 
  @Schema(name = "validatedInteger", required = false)
  public Integer getValidatedInteger() {
    return validatedInteger;
  }

  public void setValidatedInteger(Integer validatedInteger) {
    this.validatedInteger = validatedInteger;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) {
      return true;
    }
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) {
      return false;
    }
    TestingStringValidation testingStringValidation = (TestingStringValidation) o;
    return Objects.equals(this.validatedString, testingStringValidation.validatedString) &&
        Objects.equals(this.unvalidatedString, testingStringValidation.unvalidatedString) &&
        Objects.equals(this.unvalidatedInteger, testingStringValidation.unvalidatedInteger) &&
        Objects.equals(this.validatedInteger, testingStringValidation.validatedInteger);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(validatedString, unvalidatedString, unvalidatedInteger, validatedInteger);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("class TestingStringValidation {\n");
    sb.append("    validatedString: ").append(toIndentedString(validatedString)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    unvalidatedString: ").append(toIndentedString(unvalidatedString)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    unvalidatedInteger: ").append(toIndentedString(unvalidatedInteger)).append("\n");
    sb.append("    validatedInteger: ").append(toIndentedString(validatedInteger)).append("\n");
    sb.append("}");
    return sb.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Convert the given object to string with each line indented by 4 spaces
   * (except the first line).
   */
  private String toIndentedString(Object o) {
    if (o == null) {
      return "null";
    }
    return o.toString().replace("\n", "\n    ");
  }
}
```

You'll notice that the only field with the default validation is the `unvalidatedString`.  This should be exactly what you expect.

## Final Note

The Mustache templating is very powerful and has a lot of fields available.  You can check these fields by enabling `debugModels: "true"` in your globalProperties.  This will produce an output similar to the following:

```
{
      "openApiType" : "string",
      "baseName" : "unvalidatedString",
      "getter" : "getUnvalidatedString",
      "setter" : "setUnvalidatedString",
      "dataType" : "String",
      "datatypeWithEnum" : "String",
      "name" : "unvalidatedString",
      "defaultValueWithParam" : " = data.unvalidatedString;",
      "baseType" : "String",
      "jsonSchema" : "{\r\n  \"type\" : \"string\"\r\n}",
      "exclusiveMinimum" : false,
      "exclusiveMaximum" : false,
      "required" : false,
      "deprecated" : false,
      "hasMoreNonReadOnly" : false,
      "isPrimitiveType" : true,
      "isModel" : false,
      "isContainer" : false,
      "isString" : true,
      "isNumeric" : false,
      "isInteger" : false,
      "isShort" : false,
      "isLong" : false,
      "isUnboundedInteger" : false,
      "isNumber" : false,
      "isFloat" : false,
      "isDouble" : false,
      "isDecimal" : false,
      "isByteArray" : false,
      "isBinary" : false,
      "isFile" : false,
      "isBoolean" : false,
      "isDate" : false,
      "isDateTime" : false,
      "isUuid" : false,
      "isUri" : false,
      "isEmail" : false,
      "isNull" : false,
      "isFreeFormObject" : false,
      "isAnyType" : false,
      "isArray" : false,
      "isMap" : false,
      "isEnum" : false,
      "isInnerEnum" : false,
      "isEnumRef" : false,
      "isReadOnly" : false,
      "isWriteOnly" : false,
      "isNullable" : false,
      "isSelfReference" : false,
      "isCircularReference" : false,
      "isDiscriminator" : false,
      "isNew" : false,
      "vars" : [ ],
      "requiredVars" : [ ],
      "vendorExtensions" : { },
      "hasValidation" : false,
      "isInherited" : false,
      "nameInCamelCase" : "UnvalidatedString",
      "nameInSnakeCase" : "UNVALIDATED_STRING",
      "uniqueItems" : false,
      "isXmlAttribute" : false,
      "isXmlWrapped" : false,
      "additionalPropertiesIsAnyType" : false,
      "hasVars" : false,
      "hasRequired" : false,
      "hasDiscriminatorWithNonEmptyMapping" : false,
      "hasMultipleTypes" : false,
      "schemaIsFromAdditionalProperties" : false,
      "isBooleanSchemaTrue" : false,
      "isBooleanSchemaFalse" : false,
      "datatype" : "String",
      "isEnumOrRef" : false,
      "iexclusiveMaximum" : false,
      "hasItems" : false
```

Any boolean value within that output can be checked in your template and used as a conditional, while any non-boolean value can be retrieved and used directly.  You can use this to your advantage to further customize the output of your objects.

Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks. Works perfectly. Only thing I had to do was to copy and modify the `beanValidationCore.mustache` file and then set the `templateDirectory` in the maven plugin config to the folder containing this file!

Answer (score 1):

Would it be practical in your situation to define a new component lengthLimitedString in the open-api.json/yml and use that in your request.body object definitions as schema $ref? That way the validations will be built-in to generated code and visible to calling clients and will be included any generated client code.

This could be implemented in the open-api.json/yml with a global find and replace of string.